# How to initialize firebase in vite and vue?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs3, vite

I am new in vite. I am trying to initialize the firebase app. but I am getting errors like below

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

I created a file name firebase.ts but i am not really sure where can i include this to initialize firebase globally.

[image]

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'

import { isDark } from '/@src/state/darkModeState'
import useNotyf from '/@src/composable/useNotyf'
import sleep from '/@src/utils/sleep'
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from '@firebase/auth'

const isLoading = ref(false)
const router = useRouter()
const notif = useNotyf()

const username = ref('')
const password = ref('')

const handleLogin = async () => {
  if (!isLoading.value) {
    isLoading.value = true
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), username.value, password.value)
      .then((user) => {
        isLoading.value = false
        router.push({ name: 'sidebar-dashboards-course' })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        isLoading.value = false
        notif.error(
          'There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may be deleted'
        )
      })
  }
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the any file where you are importing these? Also do ensure all the credentials are correct.

Comment: I don't want to initialize in every single file. I want this to be global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `firebase.ts`, you are initializing Firebase using the `compat` version (that let's you use the name-spaced syntax even in V9) but you are trying to use the Modular version in your Vue components. Instead, try initializing Firebase using modular SDK as well. So the `firebase.ts` should look like:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, db, storage };
```

Then try importing these instances in your components instead of using `get[Service]()` functions again.

```
import { auth } from "../path/to/firebase.ts" // update the path as per your dir structure

// usage: instead of getAuth() here
await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, username.value, password.value)
```